# Distinct operations/Cartesian product

Tags: java

I want to have distinct operations of numbers to get a number.

For example, for number = 5, the result should show in `System.out.println`: `2+3, 6-1, 10-4-3-2-1, 1+6-4+5+2`, the last one is important I want to have "+" and "-" operands with whatever combination which equals a number, not only 5 but very high numbers as well.

This should work for numbers larger than long. I want to work with `BigInteger`.

How do I write a code which makes such kind of calculations?

Comment: `10-4-3-2-1` and `1+6+4+5+2` don't equal 5. Can you post your input, expected output, and code of what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a complete set of such operations, it is impossible as such set would have infinitely many elements in it.

However, if you want finite number of operations, this can be done.

1. Choose a positive random integer greater than 1. It would be your number of additions or subtractions in one operation.
2. Start with another random number. This would be your first term.
3. If current number of terms + 1 equals total number of terms, choose next term to be difference of target number and evaluation of all terms so far till current term.
4. Otherwise, choose another random number, and use it as next term.
5. Repeat from step 3.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code we have tried so far. The number 5 is wrong calculated in the example cause we are working only with brakes of 1 hours since yesterday 16:30 on this and it has to be done at 12:00... =(

We have seriously no idea how to keep on. Swap + and - between numbers to get a combination of this for BigIntegers seems like an impossible task.

Only needed for 150 numbers whose values are calculated like this. A(1) = 1, A(n) = 3*(An-1)-1.

package data;

```
    import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;

    public class Example {

        private static int counter; // a counter for the recursive calls in isValueOfA

        //saves the number the user has entered
        private static String input;    

        //value to be calculated
        private static BigInteger userInput = new BigInteger("366");
        //some constant values needed for this program
        private static BigInteger bigIntThree;
        private static BigInteger bigIntOne;
        private static BigInteger bigIntZero;
        //We dont want more than 150 A(N) values so we use an array
        private static BigInteger arraySize;
        //array to save the values of a1-a150
        private static BigInteger[] vectorValues;
        //HashMap to work with values of A(n)
        private static Hashtable<Integer, BigInteger> values;

        /**
         * @param args
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            init(); 
            populateHashMap();      
            System.out.println(isValueOfA(userInput));

        }

        /**
         * Initialize everything needed
         */
        private static void init() {
            //initialize constant values
            arraySize = new BigInteger("150");
            bigIntZero = new BigInteger("0");
            bigIntOne = new BigInteger("1");
            bigIntThree = new BigInteger("3");

            //we only want 150 A(N) and save the Values of this function in this array
            vectorValues = new BigInteger[150];
            //initialize the hashmap
            values = new Hashtable<Integer, BigInteger>();
            //create the vector 
            createVector(arraySize);    
        }

        /**
         * Create the numbers with our formula A(1) = 1, A(N) = 3*A(n-1)-1
         * @param arraySize maximum 150
         * @return result recursive call
         */
        private static BigInteger createVector(BigInteger arraySize) {

            //Case for 0        
            if (arraySize.equals(bigIntZero)) {
                System.out.println("Stop beeing a fool please...");
                return bigIntZero;
            }
            //End of recursion
            if (arraySize.equals(bigIntOne)) {
                vectorValues[0] = bigIntOne;
                return bigIntOne;
            }

            //start recursion
            else {              
                Integer position = arraySize.intValue();
                BigInteger result = bigIntThree.multiply(createVector(arraySize
                        .subtract(bigIntOne)))
                        .subtract(bigIntOne);
                vectorValues[position -1] = result;
                return result;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Transport Values from the array to our Hashtable
         * @return just fills the hashtable
         */
        private static void populateHashMap()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++)
            {
                values.put(i+1, vectorValues[i]);
                System.out.println("HashMap Added key: "+ (i+1) + " with Value: " + vectorValues[i]);           
            }
        }

        /**
         * Checks if a give parameter is the users input        
         * @param number the number to check
         * @return true if it is equal
         */
        private static BigInteger isValueOfA(BigInteger number)
        { 
            System.out.println(counter++);
                if(values.contains(userInput))
                {
                    System.out.println("UserInput was " + userInput + ": Result: + "+ number);
                    return number;
                }
                else
                {
                return BigInteger.ZERO;                 
                }
        }
    }//end of class
```